# Error Copying 1 string to another in C

Tags: c, string, copying

- I was trying to copy the contents of 1 string to another (a into b) .
  I deliberately took the second string(b) to be smaller than the 1st
  one(a) .
- I copied the contents of the first one into second

  . I added WATCH on both of them . In the Debug tab , I found out that while
  copying the original string gets destroyed and the new one also
  DISPLAYED LARGER than its size.

  ```
     #include<stdio.h>
     int main()
     {
   char a[10]="What?";
   char b[2];
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<6;i++)
   {
      b[i]=a[i];
   }
   printf("This is %s",a);
   printf("\n this is b now: ",b);
   return 0;
  ```

  }
- I have attached the screenshot for the same.  I took a = a string of
  size 10 . a="WHat?" then I took a string b[2]
- After copying , I printed both a and b . I expected the output to be
  , a = "WHat?" , b="WH" But the output is coming something else.(See
  the screenshot)

**Why did the original string get destroyed ?** Has the pointer changed ? But I have made it a constant pointer .It can't be changed.

Here is the Screen shot to the problem I am facing : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8xwxwb27qis8xww/sjpt.jpg

Please Help Somebody !!

Comment: Better post your code here instead of showing us the screenshot.

Comment: You´re trying to copy 6 chars into 2 and ask why it won´t work?

Comment: And did you hear of strlen, strcpy...?

Comment: You're either overwriting the end of an array or failing to null-terminate a string or both. Given the way you've phrased the question, I'm suspecting both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in other answers, you are writing outside the bounds of the array. The original string a changes because it happens to be exactly after b in memory as you can see in the debug window.

Before the loop, memory looks like this:

```
 b  a
|00|WHat?00000|
```

After the loop, memory looks like this:

```
 b  a
|WH|at?0?00000|
```

This explains why

- a is changed
- the original questionmark in a is still there (you only write 6 characters - two into the location reserved for b, 4 (including null terminator) into the location of a)

Of course this is undefined behavior as already mentioned by Vlad Lazarenko, but it explains the behavior for your compiler/settings/version/etc.

A constant pointer only exists for the compiler. It ensures that you cannot explicitly manipulate its data, but if you have memory leaks, nothing can be guaranteed.

Answer (score 3):

1. You are copying 6 bytes into an array of two bytes, essentially invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
2. You are passing array `b` to `printf` with `%s` specifier that expects a [null-terminated string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), while `b` is most likely not null-terminated at that point, which is another undefined behavior.

Also, a null-terminated string that can fit into 2 bytes array can essentially have only one printable character, so you should not expect `b` to be "WH". At best, if you fix the copying, it can only be "W" as the second character will be a termination byte (`\0`). If you want to have two characters, either increase the array size to 3 to allow for null terminator, or simply do not use C strings and print out two bytes using "%c%c" format string.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing currently is very unsafe! It might work on Windows for some godforsaken reason, but don't do this!

The C standard library has special functions for working with strings and memory, [strcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) for example is for copying character arrays. I suggest you learn more about how strings work and how you can manipulate them.